# psycopg2: Insert multiple rows using named arguments

Tags: python-3.x, post, psycopg2

Unfortunately the psycopg2 documentations doesn't provide any details on how to perform an insertion of multiple rows using named arguments.

They show this example:

```
cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO some_table (id, created_at, updated_at, last_name)
    VALUES (%(id)s, %(created)s, %(created)s, %(name)s);
    """,
    {'id': 10, 'name': "O'Reilly", 'created': datetime.date(2020, 11, 18)}
)
```

But only applies for a single item.
I have the following code, but each time I try to run the code I got this exception:

```
 cursor.execute(sql, values)\nTypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"}
```

This is how I’m trying to perform the insertion:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, List

import psycopg2


@dataclass
class MyObject:
    job_id: str
    param_a: str
    param_b: str

    def to_dict(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {"job_id": self.job_id, "param_a": self.param_a, "param_b": self.param_b}


class DatabaseConnection:
    """
    Wrapper class to create a postgress database connection.
    Is a helper to open and close the connection.
    """

    def __init__(self, database: str = "dbname") -> None:
        self.__database = database
        self.__connection = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.__connection = psycopg2.connect(
            database=self.__database,
            user="user",
            password="pasword",
            host="host",
            port="8000",
            sslmode="require",
        )
        return self.__connection

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback):
        if self.__connection:
            self.__connection.close()


def insert_values_to_db(objects: List[MyObject]) -> bool:
    try:
        with DatabaseConnection() as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            sql = (
                "INSERT INTO dbtable"
                "(job_id, param_a, param_b) VALUES"
                "(%(job_id)s, %(param_a)s, %(param_b)s);"
            )
            values = [obj.to_dict() for obj in objects]
            cursor.execute(sql, values)
            connection.commit()
    except Exception as _:
        return False

    return True
```

I'm not sure how can I use named arguments to insert many items at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Unfortunately the psycopg2 documentations doesn't provide any details on how to perform an insertion of multiple rows using named arguments.*

Yes there is:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers

> psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, sql, argslist, template=None, page_size=100, fetch=False)

> Execute a statement using VALUES with a sequence of parameters.

...

> template –

> the snippet to merge to every item in argslist to compose the query.

> If the argslist items are sequences it should contain positional placeholders (e.g. "(%s, %s, %s)", or "(%s, %s, 42)” if there are constants value…).

> If the argslist items are mappings it should contain named placeholders (e.g. "(%(id)s, %(f1)s, 42)").
> If not specified, assume the arguments are sequence and use a simple positional template (i.e. (%s, %s, ...)), with the number of placeholders sniffed by the first element in argslist.

So use `template="(%(job_id)s, %(param_a)s, %(param_b)s)"` in `execute_values()`.

As @snakecharmerb commented you can also use `executemany()` with a list of dicts also. Per the docs:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html

> executemany(query, vars_list)

> Execute a database operation (query or command) against all parameter tuples or mappings found in the sequence vars_list.

**Though**:

> Warning

> In its current implementation this method is not faster than executing execute() in a loop. For better performance you can use the functions described in Fast execution helpers.

FYI, in `pscyopg(3)` the fast execution helpers do not exist and you have only `executemany()`. This is mitigated by `psycopg` using pipeline mode. Read information at link below for what that means. Short version it can provide performance improvements for multiple commands:

https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/pipeline.html#pipeline-mode

For this discussion the important part is:

> Starting from Psycopg 3.1, executemany() makes use internally of the pipeline mode; as a consequence there is no need to handle a pipeline block just to call executemany() once.